# how to run an application and pass username and password to that application

Tags: c#, oracle, authentication

I want to run oracle 10g enterprise edition application from c# window form application and i want to pass the username and password to login page of the oracle automatically...oracle must be logged in without any effort to enter the login username and password.

I can run the application by following code:

```
Process.Start("sqlplusw.exe");
```

but I dont know how to pass username and password to this application automatically from c#  form.

Comment: Are you saying that you want your C# application to invoke the Windows version of the SQL*Plus utility?  First, do you realize that this utility no longer exists if the user installs the 11g Oracle client?  And the 10g Oracle client is no longer available for download? It seems odd that you'd want to create an application with this sort of built-in obsolescence.

Comment: so instead of using odp.net, you want to fork a process to run sqlplus?

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a92157/ch3.htm):

> You can optionally include your login username and password separated by a slash (/), and a remote database to connect to, for example:
>
> `C:\> SQLPLUSW username/password@connect_identifier`

Therefore, you should be able to do:

```
Process.Start("sqlplusw.exe", "username/password@connect_identifier");
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found This:

```
sqlplus user/password@dbname
```

Here http://www.fehily.com/books/createdb/sql-3rd-oracle-10g.html

Is that what you meant ?